# How to shoving tkinter function result in a new window?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to make a staffing calculator using GUI tkinter in python I expect to get the function calculation results once I fill all entries and click on calculate button in a new window (master) based on the entry but unfortunately I got an empty label in the new window also I am not reeving any error to fix, would you please help me?, here is my code and screen shot:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Workload Staffing Calculator")
#Header 
headerlab = Label(root, text="Please fill the below form and click calculate to get the required staff.").grid(row=0,columnspan=2,pady=20,padx=20)

#Inputs names
vollabel = Label(root, text="Volumes").grid(padx=0,pady=10)
ahtlabel = Label(root, text="AHT (sec.)").grid(padx=0, pady=10)
Occlabel = Label(root, text="Occupancy (%)").grid(padx=0, pady=10)
Shrinklabel = Label(root, text="Shrinkage (%)").grid(padx=0, pady=10)
weekendlabel = Label(root, text="Days Off").grid(padx=0, pady=10)
Shiftlabel = Label(root, text="Shift Duration (h)").grid(padx=0, pady=10)

#Entry inptus
volentry = Entry(root, width=10, borderwidth=3)
ahtentry = Entry(root, width=10, borderwidth=3)
occentry = Entry(root, width=10, borderwidth=3)
shrinkentry = Entry(root, width=10, borderwidth=3)
weekendentry = Entry(root, width=10, borderwidth=3)
shiftentry = Entry(root, width=10, borderwidth=3)
#shoving inputs on screen
volentry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20)
ahtentry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=20)
occentry.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=20)
shrinkentry.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=20)
weekendentry.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=20)
shiftentry.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=20)


#Calculate Fuction

def calstaff() : 

    v = volentry.get()
    a = ahtentry.get()
    o = occentry.get()
    s = shrinkentry.get()
    w = weekendentry.get()
    sh = shiftentry.get()
    required = (int(v) * int(a)) / (int(sh) * 3600)
    total = required * (7 / (7 - int(w))) * (1 + float(s))
    newwindow = Tk()
    newwindow.title("The required is: ")
    result = Label(newwindow, textvariable=total).pack()
    return result
#calculate button
calculate = Button(root, text="Calculate", command=calstaff)
calculate.grid(padx=20,pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: You can't use `textvariable=` to refer to an ordinary Python variable; that's for Tk Var types such as `IntVar` or `StringVar`.  Just use `text=`.  Also, you need to use `Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()` to create additional windows - a second call to `Tk()` creates an entirely independent Tk environment, you'll run into all sorts of problems due to things being defined in one environment, and therefore not available in the environment you're trying to use them in.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use `Tk()` more than once as it can interrupt the flow of the main loop. To create another window you should try using `Toplevel()`

Secondly, Instead of `textvariable` use `text`

Refer to the code below:

```
.
..
def calstaff() : 

    v = volentry.get()
    a = ahtentry.get()
    o = occentry.get()
    s = shrinkentry.get()
    w = weekendentry.get()
    sh = shiftentry.get()
    required = (int(v) * int(a)) / (int(sh) * 3600)
    total = required * (7 / (7 - int(w))) * (1 + float(s))
    newwindow = Toplevel()                     #TOPLEVEL() USED
    newwindow.title("The required is: ")
    result = Label(newwindow, text=total)      #text instead of textvariable
    result.pack()
    newwindow.mainloop()                       #mainloop for newwindow
..
```

Comment: I believe, it is not necessary to say `newwindow.mainloop()` for Toplevel windows